# Can we use QGIS as commercial use?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, license, enterprise, commercial

Do i need to purchase the QGIS license for commercial use? Can i use the QGIS commercially in our project?

**https://qgisenterprise.com/en/offering/packages/**

I found the few variants of QGIS but the price is not listed there, please guide me to purchase these variants.

Comment: You can use QGIS for commercial use without any fees or payment see: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/index.html. qgisenterprise is a supportmodel for commercial support - by the way - there are a lot of support companys see: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/preamble/help_and_support.html#commercial-support

Comment: QGIS is open source with GNU General Public License, you don't need to purchase any special license or credit QGIS in your products - paper, digital or metadata. As you aren't purchasing QGIS the developers offers very little in the way of customer support - this is where 3rd party companies and volunteers (like us) come in, a very small portion of the money you would have spent on a commercial package can be used for training and/or paid support. If you've used packages like ArcGIS, ERDAS Imagine, MapINFO, Global Mapper etc the concepts are close enough to *'hit the ground running'*.

Comment: ** https://qgisenterprise.com/en/offering/packages/ **

Comment: please will one of you add your comment as an answer

Comment: ok @ian-turton...done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use QGIS for commercial use without any fees or payment see: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/index.html. qgisenterprise is a supportmodel for commercial support - by the way - there are a lot of support companies see: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/preamble/help_and_support.html#commercial-support